# MVC3 Razor Code Soup - Templating?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, razor

I am trying to create my navigator to show a highlight when on certain pages. I've got the following:

```
<li>
    @if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("registration"))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Request an Invite", "index", "registration", null, new { @class = "active" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Request an Invite", "index", "registration")
    }
</li>
<li>
    @if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("login"))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "index", "login", null, new { @class = "active" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "index", "login")
    }
</li>
```

Im sure there is a better way to make this less soupy? Can someone help a beginner?

Thanks
James Woodley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion to avoid error on potential similar urls you can use

```
var contorller = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
var action = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

then to make your code smaller I will use an inline condition

```
@Html.ActionLink("Request an Invite", "index", "registration", null, (controller = "Home" && action == "registration") ? new { @class = "active" } : null)
```

I hope you get the idea